# How to add brackets to a Where Closure within a When Clause for Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to put generate outer brackets on a Combination of OR statements within a WHEN condition with Laravel Eloquent.

```
    $calls = DB::table('incoming_calls')
            ->leftJoin('scripts', 'SCRIPTID', '=', 'scripts.RECID')
            ->select('incoming_calls.RECID','INCOMING_DATE','INCOMING_TIME','SCRIPT_NAME AS MYINFO','MSG_FROM')
            ->when( (strlen(trim($searchterm))>0), function($query) use ($searchterm)
            {
                    return $query->where('MSG_FROM', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_TEL', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_MOBILE', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_COMPANY', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('incoming_calls.INFOTXT', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_ADDRESS', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_EMAIL', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%');
            })
            ->when($bid>0, function($query) use ($bid)
            {
                    return $query->where('incoming_calls.COMPANYID', "=", $bid);
            })
```

This is generating the following SQL:

```
select [incoming_calls].[RECID], [INCOMING_DATE], [INCOMING_TIME], [SCRIPT_NAME] as [MYINFO], [MSG_FROM] from [incoming_calls] left join [scripts] on [SCRIPTID] = [scripts].[RECID] where [MSG_FROM] LIKE ? or [MSG_TEL] LIKE ? or [MSG_MOBILE] LIKE ? or [MSG_COMPANY] LIKE ? or [incoming_calls].[INFOTXT] LIKE ? or [MSG_ADDRESS] LIKE ? or [MSG_EMAIL] LIKE ? and [incoming_calls].[COMPANYID] = ? order by [INCOMING_DATE] desc, [INCOMING_TIME] desc
```

Now what I need is Brackets around the OR Clauses:

```
select [incoming_calls].[RECID], [INCOMING_DATE], [INCOMING_TIME], [SCRIPT_NAME] as [MYINFO], [MSG_FROM] from [incoming_calls] left join [scripts] on [SCRIPTID] = [scripts].[RECID] where ( [MSG_FROM] LIKE ? or [MSG_TEL] LIKE ? or [MSG_MOBILE] LIKE ? or [MSG_COMPANY] LIKE ? or [incoming_calls].[INFOTXT] LIKE ? or [MSG_ADDRESS] LIKE ? or [MSG_EMAIL] LIKE ?) and [incoming_calls].[COMPANYID] = ? order by [INCOMING_DATE] desc, [INCOMING_TIME] desc
```

I understand how to do closures stand-alone and could write this using Raw SQL but I;m wanting to figure how do it with Eloquent within the ->when conditionals.  Anyone managed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via parameter grouping like this:

```
$calls = DB::table('incoming_calls')
            ->leftJoin('scripts', 'SCRIPTID', '=', 'scripts.RECID')
            ->select('incoming_calls.RECID','INCOMING_DATE','INCOMING_TIME','SCRIPT_NAME AS MYINFO','MSG_FROM')
            ->when( (strlen(trim($searchterm))>0), function($query) use ($searchterm) {
                return $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('MSG_FROM', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_TEL', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_MOBILE', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_COMPANY', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('incoming_calls.INFOTXT', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_ADDRESS', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_EMAIL', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchterm . '%');
                })
            })
            ->when($bid>0, function($query) use ($bid)
            {
                return $query->where('incoming_calls.COMPANYID', "=", $bid);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with one `where` combined with multiple `orwhere`

```
$calls = DB::table('incoming_calls')
        ->leftJoin('scripts', 'SCRIPTID', '=', 'scripts.RECID')
        ->select('incoming_calls.RECID','INCOMING_DATE','INCOMING_TIME','SCRIPT_NAME AS MYINFO','MSG_FROM')
        ->when( (strlen(trim($searchterm))>0), function($query) use ($searchterm)
        {
                return $query->where(funtion($query)  use ($searchterm){
                    $query->where('MSG_FROM', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_TEL', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_MOBILE', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_COMPANY', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('incoming_calls.INFOTXT', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_ADDRESS', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%')
                    ->orWhere('MSG_EMAIL', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchterm.'%');
                })
        })
        ->when($bid>0, function($query) use ($bid)
        {
                return $query->where('incoming_calls.COMPANYID', "=", $bid);
        })
```